# Is there a way to combine Openrewrite yaml recipes and custom recipes into a single recipe for execution?

Tags: openrewrite

I like to create a single Openrewrite migration jar that includes custom recipes and rewrite.yml recipes.
I would like it to be executed using only a one liner maven call without altering the current pom like:

```
mvn -U org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:run \
  -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=com.myorg:rewrite-migrate:1.0.0 \
  -Drewrite.activeRecipes=com.myorg.My1To2Migration
```

I can place a rewrite.yml in the jar at location `src\main\resources\META-INF\rewrite.yml` containing different standard recipes with my configurations.
I also can place a custom recipe `My1To2Migration` that returns a list of standard recipes like:

```
    @Override
    public List<Recipe> getRecipeList() {
        return Arrays
                .asList(
                        new ChangeType("com.myorg.OldType", "com.myorg.NewType", false)                        
                    );
    }
```

But, as far as I know, for execution I need to add both recipes as `activeRecipes` to the command line:

```
mvn -U org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:run \
  -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=com.myorg:rewrite-migrate:1.0.0 \
  -Drewrite.activeRecipes=com.myorg.My1To2Migration,com.myorg.RecipeFromRewriteYml
```

Or add them all in the pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <activeRecipes>
      <recipe>com.myorg.My1To2Migration</recipe>
      <recipe>com.myorg.RecipeFromRewriteYml</recipe>
    </activeRecipes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is there a way to include the custom recipes from the `rewrite.yml` into the `List<Recipe> getRecipeList()` so that I only have to add `My1To2Migration` to the maven command `activeRecipes`?
For example like this pseudo code to get the idea:

```
    @Override
    public List<Recipe> getRecipeList() {
        return Arrays
                .asList(
                        new ChangeType("com.myorg.OldType", "com.myorg.NewType", false),
                        new RecipeFromYaml("rewrite.yml") 
                    );
    }
```

Or maybe through another mechanism ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to place your `rewrite.yml` file in
`src\main\resources\META-INF\rewrite\your-recipes.yml`; your path was missing in the `\rewrite\` folder. It's then likely easiest to refer to the fully qualified class name of `My1To2Migration` from your yaml file, rather than from your custom recipe. Hope that helps!

Comment: But are all recipes from the rewrite.yml file executed then ?
Or do they still _all_ have to be listed in the activeRecipes ?

Comment: Ah now I see how to do this. The recipeList in the rewrite.yml can have 1 name and many different recipes, including custom ones. Thanks.